# #1072 - Key column 'Customer_ID' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the parent table

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
Customer_ID INT(5) not null,
CustName VARCHAR(50) not null,
CustSurname VARCHAR(50) not null,
CustEmail VARCHAR(100) unique not null,
CustMobileNo INT(12) not null,
HomeAddress VARCHAR(255) not null,
Password VARCHAR(10) not null,
constraint c_cuid_pk PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I try to create the property table it shows me

> "#1072 - Key column 'Customer_ID' doesn't exist in table"

this is the child table

```
CREATE TABLE Property(
Property_ID INT(5) not null,
PhouseNumber INT(4) not null,
PstreetName VARCHAR(50) not null,
PpostCode VARCHAR(7) not null,
Pcity VARCHAR(20) not null,
constraint p_phn_pk PRIMARY KEY (Property_ID),
constraint p_cuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
references IndividualCustomer(Customer_ID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Do you see that the `RO_Property` table does not have any column called `Customer_ID`?  Then how can you expect to add a foreign key constraint to a column which does not exist?

Comment: how is that written im totally lost

Comment: whats the code to create/define that column

Comment: I transformed my comment in to an answer, with the code for your Property table.

Comment: Just adding that column by itself is not an answer/solution to your question, because there won't be any data in that column.  Does it even make sense for the table to have a foreign key `Customer_ID` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In table `Property`, you must define a column named `Customer_ID` (well it could be named anything!), then you define the `FOREIGN KEY` on it.

Your code currently tries to link `IndificualCustomer(Customer_ID)` to `Property(Customer_ID)`, but `Property(Customer_ID)` does not exist.

Declaring the constraint just links the columns, but it does not create them.

```
CREATE TABLE Property(
Property_ID INT(5) not null,
PhouseNumber INT(4) not null,
PstreetName VARCHAR(50) not null,
PpostCode VARCHAR(7) not null,
Pcity VARCHAR(20) not null,
Customer_ID INT(5) not null,
constraint p_phn_pk PRIMARY KEY (Property_ID),
constraint p_cuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
references IndividualCustomer(Customer_ID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: THANNNNNKKKK YOOOUUUU SOO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you should add a column: `Customer_ID` to your `Property` table to create your foreign key constraint:

```
Property.Customer_ID →　IndividualCustomer.Customer_ID
```

You can not make a constraint on something that does not exist. 
Or change the +++ +++ part of your table creation query to a column that exists.

```
constraint p_cuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (+++Customer_ID+++) --to be changed accordingly
references IndividualCustomer(Customer_ID)
```

**Example**: adding the `Customer_ID` column to your table declaration would give you the following code

```
CREATE TABLE Property(
Property_ID INT(5) not null,
Customer_ID INT(5) not null,
PhouseNumber INT(4) not null,
PstreetName VARCHAR(50) not null,
PpostCode VARCHAR(7) not null,
Pcity VARCHAR(20) not null,
constraint p_phn_pk PRIMARY KEY (Property_ID),
constraint p_cuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
references IndividualCustomer(Customer_ID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: THAANNNKKK YOOOUUU SOOO MUUCCHHH

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Property(
Property_ID INT(5) not null,
PhouseNumber INT(4) not null,
PstreetName VARCHAR(50) not null,
PpostCode VARCHAR(7) not null,
Pcity VARCHAR(20) not null,
Customer_ID INT(5) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Property_ID),
KEY p_cuid_fk (Customer_ID),
constraint p_cuid_fk FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
references Customer(Customer_ID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You have to add Customer_ID in the table PROPERTY.